# What is labeled program

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, terminology

I've been studying homomorphic encryption. From their instantiations, i read  Labeled Homomorphic Encryption (labHE) scheme [1](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-66402-6_10) where it combines the notion of homomorphic encryption with labeled program.

Can someone please explain to me: What is a labeled program, and it's implications on crypto. Furthermore, I need to know what is the difference between an identity program and a labeled program.